# From batch file to firefox and google in double quotes

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, arguments, quotes

I am using following command in a Windows batch file:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" https://www.google.com/search?q="'FIFA WORLD CUP 2018'"
```

It searches for:

```
'FIFA WORLD CUP 2018'
```

How can I make it search for

```
"FIFA WORLD CUP 2018"
```

i.e. whole phrase in double quotes?

I tried different combinations like `'", "" or '' or \"\'` etc, but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putting it in three double quotes, like `"""` should do the trick. Otherwise just try `\"` that should work too.

Comment: Yes, `"""` works very well. I should have tried that as well.